# Executing custom code on org entry state change

Tags: org-mode, todo

I was recently reading a blog about [Do-nothing scripting](https://blog.danslimmon.com/2019/07/15/do-nothing-scripting-the-key-to-gradual-automation/) which is about encoding the instructions for a task as a step towards automating it. It occurred to me that this would be very nice paired with org mode todo entries.

What I want is to do be able to run code contained in a task when I change the task's state from TODO -> ACTIVE.

```
* TODO Provision new user

  #+BEGIN_SRC shell
  python3 /path/to/myscript.py
  #+END_SRC

* ACTIVE Some other heading

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (message "TEST")
  #+END_SRC
```

I guess this can be achieved using `org-after-todo-state-change-hook`, but I'm unsure where to start. Could anybody offer some advice on how to go about this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a function to do this. It finds a code block with the name specified in the task properties and runs it.

Org file:

```
** ACTIVE Make tea
:PROPERTIES:
:RUN_ON_ACTIVE: make-tea
:END:

#+NAME: make-tea
#+begin_src elisp :results output
(defun ask-completed (question)
  (while (not (y-or-n-p (concat question " Completed?")))))

(ask-completed "Pour water in the kettle.")
(ask-completed "Boil the water.")
(ask-completed "Put teabag in cup.")
(ask-completed "Pour hot water in cup.")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: make-tea
```

Method in config.el

```
(defun execute-named-code-block-in-task ()
  "Execute a named source block within the current task when its state is changed to ACTIVE."
  (when (string= org-state "ACTIVE") ; Check if the state is changed to ACTIVE
    (let ((block-name (org-entry-get nil "RUN_ON_ACTIVE"))) ; Get the code block name from properties
      (when block-name
        (org-with-wide-buffer
         (save-excursion
           (org-babel-goto-named-src-block block-name)
           (org-babel-execute-src-block)))))))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'execute-named-code-block-in-task)
```